# Is there any way to control which vehicles I get?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

In Jetpack Joyride, there are a few in-game missions that require you to have a specific vehicle. (Some ask you to drive it a certain distance, or to hit a certain number of scientists, etc.)

Is there any way to make sure you get the vehicle you need? Or are you just stuck playing over and over until that vehicle pops up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None that I've found. You always have 3 missions though, so you should always be able to work on *something.*

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version, 1.3, there's a gadget that allows you to start the game in a vehicle (unless you got a Head Start in a final spin).

Each time you start the game you'll get a different vehicle, but it you retry before you die, you'll get the same vehicle again.

This makes the different vehicle missions much easier. For example, if you get the "Destroy X 5 times" just die and restart until you start with that vehicle, then destroy it and retry, it still counts as destroyed and you can do this 5 times and finish the mission quickly.

Answer (score 1):

No, you'd think you can by buying one of the magnets, but it only uses the magnet to collect more coins it does not help you get that more often

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get your favourite veichle more often but you can use the X-Ray Specs to see what is inside vehicle boxes. You can also use free ride to get a free vehicle at the start of a run, you can kill yourself until you get the one you want.